# How to bypass confirmation email on Users creation

Tags: java, rest, docusignapi

wanted to know about sending envelopes.
Right now when i'm sending the envelop for signing it has my account information shown on the signer view.
What I would like to do, is have different information shown according to the information I provide(name, email etc.). 
I know it is possible to do by adding users, but in this case - confirmation email is required to activate that account with the ability to send envelopes.
Is there a way to do that with bypassing the confirmation email?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Another way to automatically create a user in DocuSign is by using SSO. If you configure SSO with DocuSign and when user initiates IdP-initiated/SP Initiated login then automatically user gets created in DocuSign using Just-In-Time provisioning. Once a user is created then you can create an envelope using JWT and Admin Consent based Service Integration, you can find details about this type of service Integration here,
https://docs.docusign.com/esign/guide/authentication/oa2_jwt.html

Answer (score 0):

Re

> Is there a way to do that [create a new user] with bypassing the confirmation email?

No. An account user must confirm that they are opening the account. Otherwise, you'd be able to send signing requests as John Hancock or anyone else.